# Scipy use sparse array with signal.correlate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to calculate a serial correlation in Scipy using a sparse matrix, and I'm getting an error that my arrays do not have the same dimensionality, but they appear to be identical.  Example code:

```py
import numpy
import scipy.signal as signal
import scipy.sparse as sparse

my_sparse = sparse.csr_array(numpy.random.rand(10))
print(my_sparse)
print(my_sparse.shape)

my_dense = numpy.expand_dims(numpy.random.rand(10), 1).T
print(my_dense)
print(my_dense.shape)

corr = signal.correlate(my_sparse, my_dense, method="direct", mode="full")
print(corr)
print(corr.shape)
```

output:

```py
$ python test_sparse_with_correlate.py 
  (0, 0)    0.9842628978990572
  (0, 1)    0.21288927130505086
  (0, 2)    0.11321754428562536
  (0, 3)    0.02907902961562403
  (0, 4)    0.06534326022150638
  (0, 5)    0.5611332833785263
  (0, 6)    0.6693945587792903
  (0, 7)    0.6421603953803423
  (0, 8)    0.7299602339571223
  (0, 9)    0.5241172106721759
(1, 10)
[[0.5422929  0.27431614 0.65966523 0.05579376 0.41876797 0.46535913
  0.13079666 0.97518169 0.49505634 0.68287069]]
(1, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/alt_wkdir/118_serial_correlation/code/test_sparse_with_correlate.py", line 13, in <module>
    corr = signal.correlate(my_sparse, my_dense, method="direct", mode="full")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/mnt/bioinf_tools/miniconda3/envs/scipy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/signal/_signaltools.py", line 231, in correlate
    raise ValueError("in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality")
ValueError: in1 and in2 should have the same dimensionality
```

I've also tried this with the transposed versions of the arrays (so their shapes are both (10,1)) with the same resulting ValueError.

I'm using v1.11.4 of scipy.  I first uncovered the problem with an older version, created a new conda environment with latest stable scipy and seeing the same behavior.

Is it possible to use scipy.sparse with scipy.signal.correlate and if so can you tell me how?

Comment: If you look at the `correlate` [source], you'll sse that the first thing it does is `in1 = np.asarray(in1)`.  Try that with your sparse matrix and see what it produces.  The docs do not say it will work with a sparse matrix.  Don't assume that it does!

Answer (score 2):

Make the dense and sparse (1,10) arrays:

```
In [85]: arr = np.random.rand(1,10); sarr = sparse.csr_matrix(arr)

In [86]: arr
Out[86]: 
array([[0.45548693, 0.13739717, 0.01448538, 0.06410341, 0.593232  ,
        0.53930553, 0.54963769, 0.39025394, 0.71102781, 0.83568432]])

In [87]: sarr
Out[87]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

As I noted in the comment, your `correlate` tries to convert its arguments to dense arrays.  For the sparse the result is:

```
In [88]: np.asarray(sarr)
Out[88]: 
array(<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

This just wraps the sparse object in a 0d object dtype array:

```
In [90]: np.asarray(sarr).shape
Out[90]: ()
```

So clearly the dimensions are different.

I think the sparse docs warn that using sparse matrices in generic numpy code often does not work.  `numpy` is not `sparse` aware.

The correct way to make a dense array is with the matrix's own method:

```
In [92]: sarr.toarray()
Out[92]: 
array([[0.45548693, 0.13739717, 0.01448538, 0.06410341, 0.593232  ,
        0.53930553, 0.54963769, 0.39025394, 0.71102781, 0.83568432]])
```