# Scipy signal correlate direct method - calculate results for a subset of all possible lags

Tags: python, scipy, correlation

I'm trying to use scipy signal correlate with the `method="direct"` option and I'm wondering if it is possible to restrict the calculation to just a subset of all possible lags.  The size of my input arrays is on the order of 240,000,000 entries, but I'd be interested in the about a 500k lag on either side of 0.  It doesn't seem possible by looking at the API but I was curious if I missed something or there was another library to do this in python.

Note because of the size and sparseness of my data the `method="fft"` option does not work.

updates:

- the dimension of my arrays is approximately (240_000_000,)
- one of the arrays is sparse but @hpaulj looked at source code ([Scipy use sparse array with signal.correlate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748696/scipy-use-sparse-array-with-signal-correlate?noredirect=1#comment137068051_77748696)) scipy.sparse won't work with scipy.signal

I have written code to run the correlation calculation for subset of lags i.e. lag = range(-10_000,10_000) but I was curious if there was a better way and/or avoids me reinventing the wheel.

Comment: 1) What's the dimension of this data? Are both arrays 1D? 2) What % of the data is nonzero? (I ask in case `scipy.sparse` is useful to the problem.)

Comment: Good questions, I updated to include this info in the question

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data is significantly larger than the lag you are looking for, you could compute the correlation for each lag using a for.

```py
import numpy as np
def lcorr(x1, x2, maxlag):
  C = np.zeros(2*maxlag+1);
  # make sure to use arrays, not lists or other things that 
  # might generate copies when slicing
  x1 = np.asarray(x1)
  x2 = np.asarray(x2)
  for i in range(-maxlag, maxlag+1):
    # Get two lagged slices
    if i < 0:
      t1, t2 = x1, x2[-i:]
    else:
      t1, t2 = x1[i:], x2
    # Crop to both slices to same length
    t1 = t1[:len(t2)]
    t2 = t2[:len(t1)]
    # Dot product of the overlapped slices
    C[maxlag+i] = np.dot(t1, t2)
  return C
```